# Proof that there exists a 7-sided polyhedron dice

Tags: probability, geometry, dice, polyhedra

We know that we can build a polyhedron shaped dice with $2n$ faces using two regular pyramids with n-sided bases, but how can we build a fair polyhedron dice with 7 faces ? Can we generalize the technique to build any $(2n+1)$ faced fair polyhedron dice ?

**Edit:**

I'm aware that there is a polyhedron with 7 faces (pentagonal prism), I'm interested in if there is away to proof (even if a non-constructive proof) that it can be used as fair dice.

Comment: How about a pentagonal prism

Comment: Thank you for your response! But can you help me proof mathematically that a pentagonal prism can be used a fair dice ? i.e has the probability of $1/7$ of falling on each face.

Comment: I'm sure you've already considered this but you can also use a 14-sided dice with each label shared by two sides to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @AhmedWessam: For a "flat" prism, like a coin, the chances of landing on top or bottom bases are about 50-50, while chances of landing on a lateral side are effectively nil. On the other hand, with a "tall" prism, like a pencil, the lateral sides account for almost-all the outcomes, with the bases getting almost-none. It stands to reason that there "should be" a point between "flat" and "tall" where the lateral sides and bases become equally likely. Finding that point for an actual, physical die is probably best considered by the folks in [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Type "fair 7-sided dice" into Google and report back to us on what you find.

Comment: @Blue The question with dice that don't have complete symmetry is whether the same die will give fair results when rolled on different surfaces or when released at different velocities. I would use a pencil with points at both ends so that it always ends up on a long side.

Comment: @DavidK: You are correct. Indeed, my use of "should be" was intended to raise a measure of doubt in my casual reasoning; I should have been clearer, but I was running out of comment characters. :) Now that I have characters to spare ... I suggested consulting Physics.SE precisely because the folks there would seem more apt to address the types of real-world issues you raise, along with detailing aspects of center of mass and moments of inertia and all that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for the suggestion, I've already done of course before asking the question. I'm aware there is a fair 7-sided dice but I'm trying to come up with a mathematical model or proof of it in order to generalize for (2n+1)-sides if possible.

Comment: @BLUC Of course! that may do the trick in a practical scenario but I'm more interested in the mathematical representation of specifically the 7-sided dice and generally (2n+1)-sided dice.

Comment: "I've already done of course before asking the question." I don't know what you mean by "of course". Every day, hundreds of questions get posted to this website that could be answered by a Google lookup the poster didn't do. How am I supposed to know you exercised due diligence, when hundreds don't, and when you give no indication whatsoever in the wording of your question that you have made the slightest effort to look into it? Please be more forthcoming, and edit into your question the extent of your research, and what you have found, so others don't waste their time and yours (continued)

Comment: ...by telling you things you already know.

Comment: I think my question is indeed sufficient and is to the point. I'm asking if there is a mathematical way of building such thing. If you have read previous comments, that is made clear.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Moreover, Your sarcastic comment "Type fair 7-sided dice" adds no value so I don't know what piece of information you told me that caused a waste of your time.

Comment: Sarcasm is in the eye of the beholder. My comment was meant to be a helpful suggestion to someone who had given no indication of having thought of consulting Google. I don't want *others* to waste their time – I wrote nothing about wasting my time. I still think it would be a good idea for you to edit into your question a summary of the things you already know about. Why should we have a one-way street here, with you taking but not giving, when we could all be sharing what we know?

Comment: By the way, I approve of the recent edit you made. It's the only thing stopping me from voting to close the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry If I read your suggestion incorrectly then. I'm not sure about if I have to mention that I did search google in the question, I'm sure lots of people do ask without searching as I've seen on other SE sites.

Comment: You don't *have to* do anything. But it's a courtesy if as part of a question you share what you know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your time and sorry again for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

My answer will probably get deleted because it's not a real answer, but I just wanted to list a few resources that might provide inspiration for your problem, and it would be awful trying to add this list as a comment.

Edward Taylor Pegg, *A Complete List of Fair Dice*

http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/37-Fair%20Dice/thesis/thesis7.html

The thesis addresses the problem of asymmetric dice and provides some mathematical models, so it seems relevant to your question.

Antonio Recuenco-Munoz, *The Physics of Dice*

https://www.geocities.ws/dicephysics/Recuenco-Munoz_Presentation.pdf

Just a power point with some useful information.

Strzalko et al., *Can The Dice Be Fair By Dynamics*

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrzej_Stefanski/publication/220265123_Can_the_Dice_be_Fair_by_Dynamics/links/00b49516fc20417349000000/Can-the-Dice-be-Fair-by-Dynamics.pdf

> We consider the dynamics of the three-dimensional model of the die which can bounce with dissipation on the table. It is shown that for the realistic values of the initial energy the probabilities of the die landing on the face which is the lowest one at the beginning is larger than the probabilities of landing on any other face.

Let me know if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a septagon then add pyramids on the ends so it can't land on either end. This will be fair if you only consider the 7 sides that it can possibly land on while ignoring the 14 impossible sides.

Regarding the pentagonal prism, by definition it cannot be a fair die. However, my experimental data suggests that if the ratio of the height to the radius is about 1.582, all 7 sides are equally likely if you drop it on a hard surface.